# To partition the unity by translating a single function

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I am trying to show that there exists a (real or complex-valued) function $\psi \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ having the following properties:

1. The support of $\psi$ is contained in the unit ball $B(0, 1)$. **EDIT** As Daniel Fischer points out, this condition cannot be satisfied, at least for $n>4$. The "right" condition is that $\psi$ be supported in the unit *cube*.
2. The sum of all integer translates of $\psi$ is $1$, that is $$\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}^n} \psi(x+k)=1,\qquad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n.$$
3. The sum of the squares of the integer translates of $\psi$ is between two constants: $$0< c \le \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}^n} \lvert \psi(x+k)\rvert^2\le C,\qquad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n.$$

The existence of a function with those properties is assumed implicitly in the paper that I am reading ${}^{[1]}$, but this does not seem that obvious to me. Can you give me some hint, at least?

---

${}^{[1]}$ S. Lee, "On the pointwise convergence of solutions to the Schrödinger equation in $\mathbb{R}^2$", IMRN (2006), pp.1-21. The function $\psi$ appears in the Appendix.

Comment: $$\psi_0(x)=\begin{cases} 1 - \lvert x\rvert &, \lvert x\rvert \leqslant 1\\ 0 &, \lvert x\rvert > 0\end{cases}$$ Then $\psi(x_1,\,\dotsc,\,x_n) = \psi_0(x_1)\cdot \dotsc \cdot \psi_0(x_n)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Great, but that's not smooth... Should I just regularize it with a convolution?

Comment: Ah, sorry, overlooked that constraint. But taking a partition of unity on $\mathbb{R}$ and multiplying the componentwise partitions is the way. If you just regularize the above with a convolution, you lose the support in the unit ball, so we need $\psi_0 \equiv 1$ in a neighbourhood of $0$, and $\equiv 0$ near $\pm 1$. But taking a piecewise linear function and reguarising works.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Please make this last comment into an answer, so that I can upvote & accept it. (By the way, there is an infinitesimal glitch: the support of the function $\psi(x)=\psi_0(x_1)\ldots\psi_0(x_n)$ is the unit *cube*, rather than the unit ball. But that is totally not important.)

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that we don't get support in the unit ball that way if we use the Euclidean distance to define the ball.

Comment: For $n \geqslant 4$, one can't have $\psi$ with support in the (Euclidean) unit ball, since the translates of the open unit ball don't cover the entire space. For $n = 4$, the point with all coordinates $1/2$ has distance $1$ from the nearest lattice points, for $n > 4$, the distance is $> 1$ (namely $\sqrt{n}/2$).

Comment: @DanielFischer: This is a great observation, thank you. The referenced paper speaks of the unit ball, so it is a minor error of the author. Nevertheless, the whole argument pushes through with the unit cube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a continuous partition of unity on $\mathbb{R}$ obtained by translation of a single function, say

$$\psi_0(x) = \begin{cases} 1 &, \lvert x\rvert \leqslant \frac14\\ \frac32 - 2\lvert x\rvert &, \frac14 < \lvert x\rvert \leqslant \frac34\\
0 & \lvert x\rvert > \frac34\end{cases}$$

It is easy to check that $\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} \psi_0(x+k) \equiv 1$.

Now take an approximation of the identity $\varphi$ with compact support in $\left[-\frac18, \frac18\right]$ and convolve,

$$\psi_1 := \psi_0 \ast \varphi.$$

The support of $\psi_1$ is contained in $\left[-\frac78,\frac78\right]$, $\psi_1$ is smooth, and

$$1 \equiv \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \psi_1(x+k) =  \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} (\psi_0 \ast \varphi)(x+k) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \tau_k(\psi_0 \ast \varphi) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} (\tau_k \psi_0)\ast\varphi = \left( \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \tau_k\psi_0\right)\ast \varphi,$$

since the supports of the $\tau_k\psi_0$ are a locally finite family.

Then the function

$$\psi(x_1,\, \dotsc,\, x_n) := \prod_{k=1}^n \psi_1(x_k)$$

has almost the required properties (it support is not contained in the unit ball, but in the cube). However, since "But that is totally not important", let's take that.